# Unable to display a response from Axios

Tags: javascript, axios

I am new to using Axios and struggling to display anything from a response function. I'm mainly interested to see see at least the response status. The only output I can see is when there is a 4xx code returned, but nothing when the call is successful.

Below is my code, any help would be appreciated:

```
  setServiceGroupPromise(){

    //Read data from ./data/sourcingRules.txt

        let filePath = './data/sourcingRules.txt';
var fileData = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');

console.log(fileData);
let postURL = `${siteConfig}`;

    const config = {
        method: 'post',
        url: postURL,
        params: {
            'apiKey': process.env.SHIPPING_SERVICE_API_KEY
        },

        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/xml',            
        },
        data: fileData
        };
        console.log(`Post request going to: ${postURL}`);

      axios(config)
            .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                console.log(response.status);    
                
        })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('The following error occurred : ' + error.message);      
             });
          
}
```

Comment: what do you want exactly?

Comment: Be mindful about code indentation when you submit to stackoverflow. It's near impossible for people to understand what is going wrong here.
Additionally, try to make a smaller case leaving all the specifics out. ie, just import Axios and do a simple request.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not seeing anything from the `console.log(response.data)`, try logging something like `console.log({response})`, or `console.log('show me something', response.data)`